# What is meant by "No limiting action remains there"? MN 99

Tags: sutras

In the discourse on the four Divine Abodes, what is meant by "... no limiting action remains there, none persists there."

> Here a bhikkhu abides pervading one quarter with a mind imbued with
>   benevolence, likewise the second, likewise the third, likewise the
>   fourth; so above, below, around, and everywhere, and to all as to
>   himself, he abides pervading the all-encompassing world with a mind
>   imbued with benevolence, abundant, exalted, immeasurable, without
>   hostility, and without ill will. When the deliverance of mind by
>   benevolence is developed in this way, **no limiting action remains
>   there, none persists there**....

http://obo.genaud.net/dhammatalk/bd_dhammatalk/dhamma_talk/subhasutta.htm

[MN 99](http://obo.genaud.net/dhamma-vinaya/pts/mn/mn.099.horn.pts.htm)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am not sure but i think it is something like this from [MN 43](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.043.than.html):

> "The immeasurable awareness-release, the nothingness awareness-release, the emptiness 
>   awareness-release, the theme-less-awareness-release: There is a way of
>   explanation by which these qualities are different in meaning &
>   different in name, and there is a way of explanation by which these
>   qualities are one in meaning and different only in name.
>
> "And what is the way of explanation by which these qualities are
>   different in meaning & different in name? There is the case where a
>   monk keeps pervading the first direction[4] — as well as the second
>   direction, the third, & the fourth — with an awareness imbued with
>   good will. Thus he keeps pervading above, below, & all around,
>   everywhere & in every respect the all-encompassing world with an
>   awareness imbued with good will: abundant, expansive, immeasurable,
>   free from hostility, free from ill will.
>
> "He keeps pervading the first direction — as well as the second
>   direction, the third, & the fourth — with an awareness imbued with
>   compassion ... an awareness imbued with appreciation...
>
> "He keeps pervading the first direction — as well as the second
>   direction, the third, & the fourth — with an awareness imbued with
>   equanimity. Thus he keeps pervading above, below, & all around,
>   everywhere & in every respect the all-encompassing world with an
>   awareness imbued with equanimity: abundant, expansive, immeasurable,
>   free from hostility, free from ill will.
>
> "This is called the immeasurable awareness-release.
>
> "And what is the nothingness awareness-release? There is the case
>   where a monk, with the complete transcending of the dimension of the
>   infinitude of consciousness, [perceiving,] 'There is nothing,' enters
>   & remains in the dimension of nothingness. This is called the
>   nothingness awareness-release.
>
> "And what is the emptiness awareness-release? There is the case where
>   a monk, having gone into the wilderness, to the root of a tree, or
>   into an empty dwelling, considers this: 'This is empty of self or of
>   anything pertaining to self.'[5] This is called the emptiness
>   awareness-release.
>
> "And what is the theme-less awareness-release? There is the case where
>   a monk, through not attending to all themes, enters & remains in the
>   theme-less concentration of awareness.[6] This is called the
>   theme-less awareness-release.
>
> "This is the way of explaining by which these qualities are different
>   in meaning & different in name.
>
> "And what is the way of explaining whereby these qualities are one in
>   meaning and different only in name?
>
> *"Passion, friend, is a making of limits. Aversion is a making of*
>   *limits. Delusion is a making of limits. In a monk whose fermentations*
>   *are ended, these have been abandoned, their root destroyed, made like*
>   *a palmyra stump, deprived of the conditions of development, not*
>   *destined for future arising. Now, to the extent that there is*
>   *immeasurable awareness-release, the unprovoked awareness-release is*
>   *declared the foremost. And this unprovoked awareness-release is empty*
>   *of passion, empty of aversion, empty of delusion.*
>
> *"Passion is a something. Aversion is a something. Delusion is a something. In a 
>   monk whose fermentations are ended, these have been abandoned, their
>   root destroyed, made like a palmyra stump, deprived of the conditions
>   of development, not destined for future arising. Now, to the extent
>   that there is nothingness awareness-release, the unprovoked
>   awareness-release is declared the foremost. And this unprovoked
>   awareness-release is empty of passion, empty of aversion, empty of
>   delusion.
>
> "Passion is a making of themes. Aversion is a making of themes.
>   Delusion is a making of themes. In a monk whose fermentations are
>   ended, these have been abandoned, their root destroyed, made like a
>   palmyra stump, deprived of the conditions of development, not destined
>   for future arising. Now, to the extent that there is theme-less
>   awareness-release, the unprovoked awareness-release is declared the
>   foremost. And this unprovoked awareness-release is empty of passion,
>   empty of aversion, empty of delusion.
>
> "This, friend, is the way of explaining whereby these qualities are
>   one in meaning and different only in name."*

Therefore i would guess that when it is said;
*"When the deliverance of mind by loving kindness is developed in this way, no limting action remain there, none persists there"*
It means that a mind established in the pervading everywhere & in every respect the all-encompassing world with an awareness imbued with good will etc does not give rise to mental, verbal and bodily deeds which would be limiting one's potential for the unprovoked awareness-release which is declared as the superior to the measureless release.

> Now, to the extent that there is immeasurable awareness-release, the unprovoked awareness-release is declared the foremost. And this unprovoked awareness-release is empty of passion, empty of aversion, empty of delusion.

Comment: It's the same word, anyway: *pamāṇaka* ("measuring by") in MN 99, and *appamāṇā* ("boundless, unlimited") in MN 43.

Answer (score 0):

Ven. Bodhi's translation for MN 99:

> "When the deliverance of mind by loving kindness is developed in this way, no limting action remain there, none persists there"

And his note citing the Comys explanation:

> "Limiting action/pamanakatam kammam as kamma pertaining to the sense sphere/kamavacara, contrasted with a limitless or immeasureable action, namely, the jhanas pertaining to the fine-material sphere or the immaterial sphere. In this case the brahmaviharas developed to the jhanic level are intended. When a jhana pertaining to the fine material sphere or the immaterial sphere is attained and mastered, a kamma pertaining to the sense sphere cannot overpower it and gain the opportunity to yeild its own result. Rather, the kamma pertaining to the fine material sphere or the immaterial sphere overpowers the sense spheere kammas and produces its results. Obstructing the result of the sense sphere kammas, the brahmavihara that has been mastered leads to rebirth in the company of Brahma."

Answer (score 0):

I think the metaphor of the trumpeter in the sutta explains the meaning, namely, there is loving-kindness for everyone & everything (except the 'Comy'), without limit, in all directions:

> ***Suppose there was a powerful horn blower. They’d easily make themselves heard in the four directions.*** In the same way, when the
>   heart’s release by equanimity has been developed and cultivated like
>   this, any limited (pamāṇakataṃ) deeds (kammaṃ) they’ve done don’t
>   remain or persist there. (Sujato)
>
> ---
>
> ***Just, Vāseṭṭha, as a mighty trumpeter makes himself heard—and that
>   without difficulty —in all the four directions***; even so of all things
>   that have shape or life, there is not one that he passes by or leaves
>   aside, but regards them all with mind set free, and deep-felt love.
>   (T.W Rhys Davids)
>
> ---
>
> *... no limiting action remains there, none persists there. (Bhikkhu Bodhi)*

The above said, I particularly recommend the answer of [user 1231546](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/users/8527/1231546), particularly the use of [MN 43](https://suttacentral.net/mn43/en/sujato) for explanation. As cited by [user 1231546](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/users/8527/1231546), the relevant passage is:

> *Greed, hate, and delusion are makers of **limits**.*
>
> *Rāgo kho, āvuso, **pamāṇaka**raṇo, doso pamāṇakaraṇo, moho pamāṇakaraṇo.*
>
> *A mendicant who has ended the defilements has given these up, cut them off at the root, made them like a palm stump, and obliterated
>   them, so they are unable to arise in the future.*
>
> *The unshakable heart’s release is said to be the best kind of **limitless heart’s release (loving-kindness release)**.*
>
> *Yāvatā kho, āvuso, **appamāṇā cetovimuttiyo**, akuppā tāsaṃ cetovimutti aggamakkhāyati.*
>
> *That unshakable heart’s release is empty of greed, hate, and delusion.*
>
> *Sā kho panākuppā cetovimutti suññā rāgena, suññā dosena, suññā mohena.*